# SQL select top SUM grouped by week

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

How would I need to change the following SQLite3 query to get just the row with highest totals grouped by week:

```
SELECT 
strftime('%W', date(p.match_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS week_number,
sum(red_cards + yellow_cards) AS cards, user_id
FROM user_records
GROUP BY week_number, user_id
ORDER BY week_number, cards DESC
```

The above query returns the following results:

```
week_number - cards - user_id
44            5       1
44            1       2
45            2       2
45            1       1
```

I'm trying to show just the top row for each week:

```
week_number - cards - user_id
44            5       1
45            2       2
```

Is there some trick to adjust the query to drop the unnecessary extra rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT s.* FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        strftime('%W', date(p.match_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS week_number,
        sum(red_cards + yellow_cards) AS cards, user_id
    FROM user_records
    GROUP BY week_number, user_id) s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM user_records p
                 WHERE strftime('%W', date(p.match_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) = s.week_number
                 GROUP BY p.user_id
                 HAVING SUM(red_cards + yellow_cards) > s.cards)
```

Comment: With a quick test, this seems to give the correct results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, use a CTE.  Then a simple `JOIN` or `WHERE` clause will do:

```
WITH w as (
      SELECT strftime('%W', date(p.match_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS week_number,
             SUM(red_cards + yellow_cards) AS cards, user_id
      FROM user_records
      GROUP BY week_number, user_id
     )
SELECT w.*
FROM w
WHERE w.cards = (SELECT MAX(w2.cards)
                 FROM w w2
                 WHERE w2.week_number = w.week_number
                )
ORDER BY week_number;
```

Note that this will return multiple rows if multiple rows have the same maximum value for a given week.

Comment: This gives correct result also, thanks! Returning multiple rows in case of same max value is a good addition. By the way, when I run this query in SQLiteStudio, it displays correct result, but it also gives this warning: "SQLiteStudio was unable to extract metadata from the query. Results won't be editable." Is this something to worry about?

Comment: @J.Harwood . . . That is not anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can return the row with the highest value in a group with max():

```
SELECT week_number,
       max(cards) AS cards,
       user_id
FROM (SELECT strftime('%W', date(p.match_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS week_number,
             sum(red_cards + yellow_cards) AS cards,
             user_id
      FROM user_records
      GROUP BY week_number, user_id)
GROUP BY week_number
ORDER BY week_number;
```

Comment: This solution also returns correct results. Thanks!